# Windows Server - turning on automatic updates, but turning off automatic restart

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2008-r2, automatic-update

I have a Windows Server which is used to host a bunch of web apps. I want important updates to be automatically downloaded/installed, but I don't want the system to restart automatically after this happens (I want to periodically remote in and restart if necessary).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a registry key that controls rebooting after update.

Create:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers
```

and set it to 1.

This should stop reboots while there is an active user.

There is a more brute force way - which is to delete *wuauclt.exe*, usually found in the Windows\system directory.  This is the exe that causes the auto restart.  However, it is often recreated during an update so this isn't always effective.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, on windows 10 and up you can use the built-in program "sconfig"

```
> sconfig
> 5 (for Windows Update Settings)
> D ( for download only )
```

( I know the original question is for Windows 2008R2, but I have not seen any mention of this Win10 option on Superuser.  Hopefully when someone asks about this, they can find this answer, and even copy it as needed.)